# How to change language in citation in text

Tags: biblatex, languages, apa-style

I'm having trouble changing the language for when I am citing in the text with only two authors.

For instance, instead of writing "...MacKinnan and Brittain", I want it to write "...MacKinnan og Brittain" for danish.

I'm using LaTex compiler and apa citation style.

My preamble code for my bibliography and citing is:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
```

Is it possible to add something to change the "and" in the citation text?
I'm relatively new to LateX and overleaf, so I'm not the best at adding packages. If this is needed, please explain it to me as well on how to insert this :)

Some further explanation of my problem and my citing.
The following is my sentence in the text

```
Denne artikel af \cite{MacKinnon2020} omhandler implementering af mHealth i sundhedssektoren.
```

resulting in

[image]

in the compiled pdf version.

My bib.bib coding:

```
@article{MacKinnon2020,
   author = {Grant E. MacKinnon and Evan L. Brittain},
   doi = {10.1016/j.chest.2019.10.015},
   issn = {00123692},
   issue = {3},
   journal = {Chest},
   month = {3},
   pages = {654-664},
   title = {Mobile Health Technologies in Cardiopulmonary Disease},
   volume = {157},
   year = {2020},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please , as usual here, show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Do not forget to add the used bib entries ...

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add some information above, however, I'm not sure if I've added what you're asking for?

Comment: `biblatex-apa` speaks Danish, so if you tell LaTeX that your document is written in Danish (which you should really do if that is the case - otherwise words won't hyphenate properly and other bits of your document won't be translated either), you should get "og" automatically as can be seen in https://gist.github.com/moewew/fa126c73fc992f3f3b828004add90785.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! I didn't realize a language package was used, but I found it in preamble and changed it!

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex-apa` speaks Danish if you tell it to. If the citations come out as English in a Danish document, you probably haven't configured `babel`/`polyglossia` properly.

```
\documentclass[danish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{MacKinnon2020,
  author  = {Grant E. MacKinnon and Evan L. Brittain},
  doi     = {10.1016/j.chest.2019.10.015},
  issn    = {00123692},
  number  = {3},
  journal = {Chest},
  month   = {3},
  pages   = {654-664},
  title   = {Mobile Health Technologies in Cardiopulmonary Disease},
  volume  = {157},
  year    = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Denne artikel af \textcite{MacKinnon2020} omhandler implementering af mHealth i sundhedssektoren.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Denne artikel af MacKinnon og Brittain (2020) omhandler implementering af mHealth i sundhedssektoren.]